# Sorting icon can't include in mdbTableSort

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, mdbootstrap

I'm using angular with Bootstrap4. I want to show the column sorted or not. But I can't show which field was sorted. Because sorting icons not changing depending on ascending and descending.

```
<th aria-controls="tableSortExample" scope="col" 
  [mdbTableSort]="datatable" sortBy="columnname" >Code
              <mdb-icon fas icon="sort" ></mdb-icon>
            </th>
```